# Is there anything I should do at the end of a PHP script?

Tags: php, mysqli

On big PHP sites, is there anything that should be done at the end of its script(s)?

For example, should `mysqli_close()` be called at the end? What is its purpose? What happens if it's not called?

Also, if during the script I assign a lot of data to a `$variable`, let's say 20 MB of plain text, should I unset the `$variable` at the end of the script, or is the data automatically "thrashed" when the script/request ends?

Is there anything else that should be usually done at the end of scripts?

Comment: Resources in most cases in PHP only have the lifetime of the request.

Comment: PHP cleans up everything for you. You only need to close connections if you're handling more than one, or if the connection was persistent, etc. Memory is freed because the process ends.

Comment: I think the context is relevant. `mod_php` or a CGI variant such as `suPHP`?

Answer (score 0):

> during the script I assign a lot of data to a $variable, let's say 20 MB of plain text

You definitely should **avoid** such situations at all. With no exceptions. **Especially** on a big site.
I would sat 1Mb is max for the frontend script, but in practice 100K-200K should be enough.

> For example, should mysqli_close() be called at the end? What is its purpose?

For example, you are supposed to ask a *manual page* for this question. Where you can learn that there is absolutely no point in calling this function at the end of script execution.

Comment: -1 *You definitely should avoid such situations at all.* State your source. You're the advocate of instantly rejecting hearsay answers, yet this one is the perfect example of one.

Answer (score -1):

Using mysqli_close() helps free up database connections sooner, so it is good practice to use as soon as you no longer require the connection, though PHP does free this up as soon as a script has completed executing anyway.

As for unsetting variables or other kinds of cleanup, there really is no need. PHP collects garbage as and when the variables are no longer in use.

Comment: I'm curious as to why I got a downvote. Is any of what I said incorrect?